# Proves about $L_n$ (lower central series of a group $G$)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups, derived-subgroup

I'm trying to solve this problem from my abstract algebra course:

> The *lower central series* of a group $G$ is defined by means of
> $L_0=G$, $L_{n+1}=[G,Ln]=\langle[g,h]:g\in G,h\in L_n\rangle$, for any $n\geq
>  0$.
>
> a) Prove that $L_n\unlhd G$ for any $n\geq 0$.
>
> b) Show that we have indeed a descending series: $L_0\unrhd L_1 \unrhd
> > L_2 \cdots$.
>
> c) Prove that for any $n$, $L_n/L_{n+1}\leq Z(G/L_{n+1})$.
>
> d) Prove that the group $G$ is nilpotent if and only if $L_n=1$ for
> some $n$.

The work I've done so far:

**a)** I first started trying to solve the a) question using induction. The base case is true ($L_0=G\unlhd G$), so now I assume it verifies for some $n$ and try to prove that it also verifies for $n+1$ then. Despite this, I've not been able to see how to prove it, so I'll need help here.

**b)** This one was easy considering true the a) statement: using induction again, It's clear that $L_0\unrhd L_1$, since $L_1=[G,G]=G'$. So I try to see if for any $n$, $L_n\unrhd L_{n+1}$. Considering $[g,h]=ghg^{-1}h^{-1}\in L_{n+1}$, notice that by definition $h^{-1}\in L_n$, and since it's normal for a), then $ghg^{-1}\in L_n$ too, so we conclude that $L_n\unrhd L_{n+1}$.

For questions c) and d) I still don't know where to start.

Any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: For c) and d) see the posts here, e.g., [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1514374/group-g-is-nilpotent-if-and-only-if-gn-1-for-some-n-geq-0). Also, this is contained in books on group theory, so you can have a look. For example, see my [notes](https://homepage.univie.ac.at/Dietrich.Burde/papers/burde_54_groups.pdf), section $3.3$, page $36$ ff, so Lemma $3.3.3$ and $3.3.4$ and Proposition $3.3.5$. I think, for standard results, you should not post again here, but first look it up in a book or in some notes.

Comment: You have the definition of $L_{n+1}$ wrong, you want the subgroup generated by those commutators, not the set o commutators (which do not necessarily form a subgroup).

Comment: @DerekHolt you're right, I'll edit it now, my bad.